# sillcock leak when turned on

Tags: water

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me identify a frostfree sillcock manufacturer. The only identification is a capital "A" embossed n the side. It was purchased from a popular chain hardware store. It leaks from the valve stem when open.   The valve stem is exactly 9 1/4 inches from tip to tip and has 6 threads.  It is soldered in a very difficult place to install a new one.  It seems that there may be an "O' ring missing just behind the tip of the valve stem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your location in the world and pictures of the various bits would help us to help you. Please [edit] to add that information to the question. If it's missing an o-ring, you can frequently go to a hardware store with parts in hand to check the fit and get one; if you go the same one, they might even know what sillcock you have. Description of leak sounds like the valve stem packing, which is not usually an o-ring, but I supposed anything's possible. Non-o-ring valve stem packing material can also be had at a hardware or plumbing store.

Comment: `The only identification is a capital "A" embossed n the side` ... that's not the only identification ... how it looks is another identification

Comment: Insufficient information. Take a picture

Comment: Fred, have you tried plugging in a photo of YOUR thing, into Google Images (which knows how to do a reverse search)?

Comment: I would get some valve stem packing it is like a fat Teflon string, some is white pure PFTE and som is gray graphite impregnated wrap that around the stem many times and put the jamb or stem nut back on and tighten it will work like new for years any plumbing or big box store should have it for a few $$